# Swift: Navigation Bar is not a button

Tags: swift, xcode

Hiii !
it's my second app on Xcode.

I noticed that my navigation item is not a button but a "drop down" and I don't know why

How can I change it ? [Image: navigation item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFsQc.png)

Comment: Looks like maybe you are using ``presentViewController``. Try change to ``pushViewController`` instead

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I found out why with your comment, at first I couldn't make a pushViewController, but it was because I didn't "Embed in Navigation controller" my first view

Comment: So I will answer detail in the comment for you to save it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the comment, I will answer detail about your problem for futher reader and yourself.

As Swift there is two types of tranfering to from view controller to another view controller

First one is using `presentViewController` which is presents a view controller modally. Just like from your image and we usually use it for task you don't want user to navigate from so just two methods cancel or continue. Example: Sign In, Sign Up, ...

Second one is using `pushViewController` which will have a **Back** button just like you want in the navigation bar. And in this case you can control your own controller, callback, ... Remember to define what is root view controller by using `Embed in Navigation controller` if you use storyboard or define by code by using

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc // your view controller
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with is that your storyboard or screen is as a sheet.

[Segue set as Page Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NWaB.png)

Changing this to full screen will give it a bar, but you may need to embed the scene into a navigation control to create a bar. You can do that via Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

[Segue set to full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPXM8.png)

[Embedded into Navigation Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kat8i.png)
The navigation controller color is set to black to be noticeable.